# VBA Loop - Insert row when cell, or cells, above are not equal

Tags: excel, vba, loops, insert

The code below works, however, I want to find a way to refine & optimise the code itself. Appreciate any guidance from members. I have checked similar questions.

[image]

**Objective:**

VBA loop an excel worksheet to identify if the data in columns B & C match the cells above. If not, insert a new row & resize the range until complete.

```
Sub Insert_Row_When_Data_Is_Not_Equal()

Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

'Row 2 starting point to skip headers
x = 2

'Repeat loop until end of range
Do While Range("A" & LastRow - 1).Value <> ""

x = x + 1
    
    'If the combined data in B3 & C3 does not equal _
    'the data above, insert a new row & resize my range
    If Range("B" & x).Value & Range("C" & x).Value _
    <> Range("B" & x - 1).Value & Range("C" & x - 1).Value Then
    
        Range("B" & x).EntireRow.Insert
        
        x = x + 1
        
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
    End If
Loop

'Just for validation
Debug.Print LastRow

End Sub
```

Comment: One improvement would be to use a worksheet variable to fully qualify all of your `Range()` and `Cells()` calls.

Comment: Cheers Tim, I see what you mean from CDP's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It usually preferable to scan up the sheet when inserting or deleting rows so the loop counter is not affected.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Insert_Row_When_Data_Is_Not_Equal()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, x As Long, LastRow As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
         ' loop up the sheet
        For x = LastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1 ' header row 1
            'If the combined data in B3 & C3 does not equal _
            'the data below, insert a new row below
            If .Cells(x, "B").Value = .Cells(x + 1, "B").Value Then
                If .Cells(x, "C").Value <> .Cells(x + 1, "C").Value Then
                    .Rows(x + 1).Insert
                End If
            Else
                .Rows(x + 1).Insert
            End If
        Next
        ' recalc size
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    'Just for validation
    Debug.Print LastRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the efficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

### Insert Row After Group

- This will run fast for up to a few thousand, maybe 5 thousand rows to be inserted.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRowAfterGroup()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRowCol As String = "A"
    Const CompareColsList As String = "B,C" ' add more
    Const MaxUnion As Long = 50 ' cells per combined range
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet  ' improve
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = LastRow - FirstRow + 1
    If RowsCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' one row or no data
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Cells(FirstRow, LastRowCol).Resize(RowsCount)
    Dim CompareCols() As String: CompareCols = Split(CompareColsList, ",")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(CompareCols)
    Dim jcData As Variant: ReDim jcData(0 To cUpper)
    
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 0 To cUpper
        jcData(c) = rg.EntireRow.Columns(CompareCols(c)).Value
    Next c
    
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection

    Dim irg As Range ' Insert Range
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim irCount As Long ' Inserted Rows Count
    
    For Each iCell In rg.Cells
        r = r + 1
        If r > 1 Then ' skip the first row
            For c = 0 To cUpper
                If StrComp(CStr(jcData(c)(r, 1)), CStr(jcData(c)(r - 1, 1)), _
                        vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' case-insensitive
                    irCount = irCount + 1
                    If irg Is Nothing Then ' combine cells into range
                        Set irg = iCell
                    Else ' alternate to get one-cell ranges
                        Set irg = Union(irg, iCell.Offset(, 1 - irCount Mod 2))
                    End If
                    If irCount Mod MaxUnion = 0 Then ' write range to collection
                        coll.Add irg
                        Set irg = Nothing
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next iCell
    
    If irCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then coll.Add irg
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each irg In coll
        irg.EntireRow.Insert
    Next irg
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Rows inserted: " & irCount, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @CDP1802: Thanks again. Corrected.

Comment: Since you really only want to collect rows with `irg.EntireRow.Insert` not sure the complexity of the if block around `Set irg = Union(irg, iCell.Offset(, 1))` is necessary.

Comment: Try without it and weep: it's the 'tiny' difference compared to deleting or hiding rows. While combining the cells, there could be a range with consecutive cells e.g. `A3:A4` and it would insert two consecutive rows instead. With this alternate offsetting, I'm getting e.g. `A3` and `B4` so both rows get inserted correctly.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Without the if just `Set irg = Union(irg, iCell.Offset(, 1 - irCount Mod 2))`

Comment: Thanks for your input guys. Useful for me to see an advanced method of completing the task.

Comment: @CDF1802: Thanks again. Corrected.